# Check if all elements in nested iterables evaluate to False

Tags: python

I have the following code (a list of tuples):

```
x = [(None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None)]
```

How would I know that this essentially evaluates to `False`?

In other words, how could I do something like:

```
if not x: # x should evaluate to False
    # do something
```

Comment: You may want to clarify what then should evaluate to `True` and what to `False`. Presumably having *anything* in the nested tuples that is true-ish should have the opposite outcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use nested [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) calls:

```
if not any(any(inner) for inner in x):
```

`any()` returns `False` only if *all* of the elements in the iterable passed to it are `False`. `not any()` thus is `True` only if all elements are false:

```
>>> x = [(None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None)]
>>> not any(any(inner) for inner in x)
True
>>> x = [(None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, 1)]
>>> not any(any(inner) for inner in x)
False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any` with `itertools.chain`, it is faster than nested `any` as no python for-loop is required:

Few other alternatives are:

```
not any (chain.from_iterable(x))
not any (chain(*x))
not any(map(any,x))
not any(imap(any,x))   #itertools.imap
```

## Timing comparisons:

```
>>> from itertools import chain,imap
>>> x = [(None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None)]
>>> %timeit not any (chain.from_iterable(x))       #winner
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 us per loop
>>> %timeit not any (chain(*x))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 us per loop
>>> %timeit not any(any(inner) for inner in x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 us per loop
>>> %timeit not any(map(any,x))
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 us per loop
>>> %timeit not any(imap(any,x))
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 us per loop


>>> x = [(None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None)]*1000
>>> %timeit not any (chain.from_iterable(x))      #winner
1000 loops, best of 3: 462 us per loop
>>> %timeit not any (chain(*x))
1000 loops, best of 3: 537 us per loop
>>> %timeit not any(any(inner) for inner in x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop
>>> %timeit not any(map(any,x))
1000 loops, best of 3: 672 us per loop
>>> %timeit not any(imap(any,x))
1000 loops, best of 3: 765 us per loop

>>> x = [(None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None)]*10**5
>>> %timeit not any (chain.from_iterable(x))       #winner
10 loops, best of 3: 50.1 ms per loop        
>>> %timeit not any (chain(*x))                  
10 loops, best of 3: 70.3 ms per loop
>>> %timeit not any(any(inner) for inner in x)
10 loops, best of 3: 127 ms per loop
>>> %timeit not any(map(any,x))
10 loops, best of 3: 76.2 ms per loop
>>> %timeit not any(imap(any,x))
1 loops, best of 3: 64.9 ms per loop
```